# Installing wordpress on subdomain of Business Catalyst site

Tags: business-catalyst

I would like to install wordpress on a subdomain of a business catalyst site. Is this possible and how can I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't install Wordpress onto the business catalyst provided hosting as it's not allowed.

What you can do however, is purchase hosting seperately and then point your subdomain to that hosting from within BC or the domain DNS management tool.

That way you can still have wpsubdomain.domain.com however you'd have Business Catalyst hosting and another hosting resource to consider the fees for.

http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/kb/add-subdomain.html

Hope this helps.